# How to enable nano-like whitespace highlighting in vim?

Tags: vim

`nano` has a useful bit of syntax highlighting that actually highlights whitespace (tabs and spaces), under two conditions: (1) the whitespace does not have a non-whitespace character between either the last character or the beginning of the line and it, and (2) that the file is source code and not plain, plain text (as in a shopping list).  How can I emulate this kind of behavior in `vim`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use `set list` and `set listchars` in `.vimrc` to show `tabs` and trailing `white spaces`, you can use a condition for selective file type like this.

```
if !(&filetype == "txt")
  set list                " show special characters
  set listchars=tab:→\ ,trail:·,nbsp:·
endif
```

So my files look like this when those charaters are present.

```
function someFunc() { // no trailing spaces here
→   var a = "hola"; // 3 trailing spaces.···
    alert(a); // this line starts with spaces instead of tab
// next a line with 4 white spaces and nothing else
····
// next a line with a couple tabs
→   →   
}
```

Note: `·` is not `.`

#### Edit

So to answer to your comment, you can do that by adding this to your `~/.vimrc`, make sure to add it after the colorscheme, or it will be `hi clear`'d.

```
if !(&filetype == "txt")
  highlight WhiteSpaces ctermbg=green guibg=#55aa55
  match WhiteSpaces /\s\+$/
endif
```

You can change the highlight colors and refine the regular expression as needed. `/\s\+$/` will match trailing spaces or tabs and lines that contain nothing but either of those 2 characters. If you only want to highlight lines with just tabs and spaces use `/^\s\+$/` instead.

Comment: `nano`, I just realized, doesn't replace the tabs and spaces, but changes them to the "black/white on green" coloring, which makes them appear as green bars.  Is there a way that I can do this instead of inserting a separate character?